Timeout on Metaflow when searching for an instance
I'm using Metaflow in Python to get data from a specific run. The way to do this is very explicit and clear on the Metaflow documentation:
Flow(flow_name)[run_id]

Very often this operation fails with a 504 Gateway Time-out. I can't find any way to increase the time here. Is there a way to deal with this issue?

The env var MF_METADATA_DB_TIMEOUT can be set for this. Reference: https://github.com/Netflix/metaflow-service/issues/448.
